# How can I get index of list in django template

Tags: django, list, templates

I have 3 list item1,item2,item3

```
views.py
context={'item0': region.objects.all(),
         'item1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
         'item2': ['one', 'two','three','four', 'five'],
         'item3': ['six', 'seven','eight','nine','ten'],
         'item4': "test",
         'item5': 5,
         'item6': range(5),
         }
```

```
return render(request, 'btscreate.html', context )
```

I tried get in template

1)

```
{% for num in item1 %}
<td> {{ num }} </td> # this work 
<td> {{ how can I get values item2 and item3 ? }} </td>
{% endfor %}
```

2. 

```
{% for num in item6 %}
<td> {{ item2.0 }} </td> # that work 
<td> {{ item2.num }} </td> # but that doesn't work
{% endfor %}
```

**how can I get values item2 and item3 ?**

Comment: whats your desired output can you share? I'm confused in question title and the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is, as far as I know, not possible within templates.

To make sure we are on the same page I will show the code in python that you want to translate to "django-template-syntax"

```py
r = range(3)
list1 = ["ape", "whale", "giraffe"]
list2 = ["brown", "blue", "yellow"]
for idx in r:
    print(list1[idx], list2[idx]
```

Solution 1:
Do it without a for-loop and access every item. Might be very tedious but still an option.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> {{ item2.1 }} </td>
    <td> {{ item3.1 }} </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> {{ item2.2 }} </td>
    <td> {{ item3.2 }} </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Solution 2:
As I said iterating over two lists simultaneously like shown in my python example is not possible within the templating-syntax. You need to `zip` those lists inside your views:
views.py:

```py
item2 =  ['one', 'two','three','four', 'five']
item3 = ['six', 'seven','eight','nine','ten']
context={'item0': region.objects.all(),
         'item1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
         'item23': zip(item2, item3)
         'item4': "test",
         'item5': 5,
         'item6': range(5),
         }
```

Then in your template you do it like this:
temp.html:

```html
<table>
{% for i2, i3 in item23 %}
<tr>
  <td> {{ i2 }} </td> 
  <td> {{ i3 }} </td> 
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

If your question's target is just how to display the index of the loop you can do like this:
temp.html:

```html
<table>
{% for i2, i3 in item23 %}
<tr>
  <td> {{ forloop.counter0 }} </td>
  <td> {{ i2 }} </td> 
  <td> {{ i3 }} </td> 
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

You can not use that forloop counter as an index for other lists similar to my python example above.

Comment: Tarquinius, Thanks.   'item23': zip(item2, item3)  this is what I needed